# SSE data write is not reaching to client (no exception system)

Tags: spring, jersey, weblogic12c, server-sent-events

I'm implementing SSE in my MicroService 
(Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 + Jax-RS 2.1 (used to register resource) + CXF 3.2.5+ + Springboot + jersey 2.25.1)

I implemented 2 approaches but both are having same issue -

1. implemented by jersey api ***org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse***

ref- https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/using-server-sent-events.htm#RESTF337

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.5.1/examples/sse-item-store-webapp

2. Spring MVC SSE implementation using SseEmmitter
      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2To3_mYT2hc

In both approaches, data is not received at client end event stream but the sample application is working fine deployed on the same WebLogic.

Seems something wrong in chunk buffer, that is not get flushed in my application but in sample code, it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sort of compression for your responses? I had the same issue on my Node.js app, I was getting a chunk err on the client. It turned out I needed to flush my response after every `write()` for the `/n/n` terminator sequence to reach the client and allow the data to be used in the listener.